# Custom jQGrid summaryType in JSON string

Tags: c#, json, jqgrid-asp.net

I am dynamically building the `colModel` for my `jQGrid` using fields from a `DataTable`.  Nearly all of it works as I hoped.  However, I am unable to use a custom `summaryType` because I can't serialize without the quotes and `jQgrid` doesn't look for the method if in quotes.

Presently, if I don't remove the ", I get the following error when loading the grid:

```
Uncaught jqGrid Grouping No such method: mysum
```

If I remove the quotes in the table, I get the following error when serializing:

```
Invalid JSON primitive: mysum.
```

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to create a solution in the view using javascript.  If you manually serialize the `colModel` to send to the view, you will have to manually deserialize.  You will not be able to parse it with a `JSON` parser because it will not be a valid `JSON` string.

One possible approach would be to use `eval()` on the string like this:

```
myObject.property = eval("mysum");
```

It should replace the string with the function.  I am not sure if it meets your needs, but will avoid both errors you listed above.